# How to set a list to multiple combination fields by name

Tags: javascript, list, combobox, get, wildcard

```js
var oCheckOptions = {
    Yes: [
        ["-"],
        ["Serviceable"],
        ["Unserviceable"]
    ],
    No: [
        ["Not Applicable"]
    ]
};

function SetCheckOptions() {
    {
        var lst = oCheckOptions[event.value];
        if((lst != null) && (lst.length > 0)) this.getField("B.Artic1").setItems(lst),
            this.getField("B.Artic2").setItems(lst),
            this.getField("A.Artic1").setItems(lst),
            this.getField("A.Artic2").setItems(lst),
            this.getField("A.Artic3").setItems(lst);
        else {
            this.getField("B.Artic1").clearItems(),
                this.getField("B.Artic2").clearItems(),
                this.getField("A.Artic1").clearItems(),
                this.getField("A.Artic2").clearItems(),
                this.getField("A.Artic3").clearItems();
        }
    }
}
```

I am a novice so thank you for your assistance.

My project is creating a dynamic PDF for mechanics. Based on the platform's configuration depends on the type of checks performed.

The problem I am running into is I am identifying each field. Is there a way to call all fields with "artic" in the name to simplify the code?  Thanks!

Comment: First of all SO isn't a code review site as things can get a bit opinionated. Your code doesn't seem like it will work, line 8 is confusing me... Make a minimum reproducible example as a snippet that can run here, with example values and people can leave comments on how to improve your code, but beyond that this question breaks the rules and can't be answered

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ZachJensz Thank you for the coaching and mentoring! I adjusted the question and added the code as a snippet.

Comment: The snippet still doesn't seem to contain everything, are you missing certain markup?

Comment: I think it is missing the actual trigger. The trigger event is 'mouse up' on the actual combination box. When Yes or No is selected, the mouse up then triggers the event. The event is called outside of the code container. I apologize it is a PDF project.